# how to limit facebook crawling of site

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api

Recently, we got complaints on our shared server from the hosting company stating the traffic is enormous. After some checking - seems as tho one of the biggest culprits is Facebook. Here's a list of top ips that are accessing the site:

```
    870 66.220.158.113
    871 66.220.152.114
    879 66.220.152.112
    880 66.220.158.112
    885 66.220.158.115
    890 66.220.158.116
    898 69.171.248.0
    904 69.171.248.7
    915 69.171.248.3
    916 66.220.158.114
    922 66.220.158.119
    924 69.171.237.115
    928 69.171.248.6
    942 66.220.158.117
    944 69.171.248.5
    945 69.171.237.112
    949 69.171.248.4
    959 69.171.248.2
    963 66.249.64.38
    978 69.171.237.116
    978 69.171.237.117
    981 69.171.237.119
    1001 69.171.237.113
    1002 69.171.248.1
    1008 66.249.64.43
    1056 69.171.237.114
    1443 157.55.39.237
    1613 157.55.39.144
    2000 157.55.39.74
    2033 157.55.39.92
```

Most of these are facebook! How can I limit Facebook from coming back so often? Seems like the og:ttl is not something Facebook recognizes anymore. I'm at a loss.

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: Do you actually deserve all that traffic? Because if you are serving something that is pretty popular on FB, then I would not try to limit FB, rather I would find an hosting solution/provider that does not complain...

Comment: Yeah it's a newspaper site in California that I've gotten to do really well in the engines and twitter and on facebook. So the traffic is earned I guess you could say

Comment: Well, it's time for an upgrade then! Migrate to a vps/dedicated server and nobody will complain anymore.